# How to read value from yaml file which are in dictionary and need to use in helm

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

This is my string in `values.yaml`:
`selectorLabels: { app.kubernetes.io/name: tinyurl }`

Yaml file looks like below:

```
name: test-dj-service
environment: prod
namespace: test-service
labels: { app.kubernetes.io/name: test-dj-service, environment: prod }
replicaCount: 1
selectorLabels: { app.kubernetes.io/name: tinyurl } <---
```

I need to use `tinyurl` in the below code under values.

Note:- `tinyurl` is variable, it will keep changing with other names.

```
{‌{ - if .Values.affinity.podAntiAffinity.preferred == true }}
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                 matchExpressions:
                 - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                   operator: In
                   values: {‌{ ---------- }} # need to pull the selectorLabels values here.
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
{‌{- end }}
```

So how I can pull this variable into values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @ShashankV's answer, you should also be able to construct your label selector using a `range` expression (in case you want to support arbitrary label selectors, with multiple labels that are read from your Values file):

```
labelSelector:
  matchExpressions:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.selectorLabels }}
  - key: {{ $key | quote }}
    operator: In
    values: {‌{ $value | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index` function

```
{{ index .Values.selectorLabels "app.kubernetes.io/name" }}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's not fetching anything ```- key: app.kubernetes.io/name operator: In values:  topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"```